# reload tableView data placed in a tabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, reloaddata

i've a tabBarController, in one tab i've a navigation controller that manage a table view. TableView works, but if in my

```
viewWillAppear
```

of the tableVieW class i add

```
[self.table reloaddata];
```

nothing appear.

where i'm wrong? it's correct to reload tableview in  tableView class or i must call the reload from another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `UITableViewDataSource` delegate is set for `self.table`. If no data source is set, or if its `count` is not more than 0, nothing will appear in your table

Comment: hello peter. my table is populate with the right data (list from a directory). if i modify this list and come back to the table tab i cannot see the change (-> reloadData is not call)

Comment: Now I understand what's going on. In such case, I use `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` or `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` to explicitly call `[self.table reloadData];`. Usually `reloadData` or `inserting/deleting rows` should be called EXPLICITLY for each update, which changed data source. If your data source is not too big, try `reloadData` whenever you updated the data source and the table view is going to be appear. Hope this was helpful.